# Definir tamanho do FloatingActionButton no Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
private FloatingActionButton createButton(int id) {

    FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(this);

    fab.setId(id);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Entrei truta");
        }
    });
    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, buttonAddCardapio.getId());
    lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, editTextCardapioHora.getId());
    lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, editTextCardapioHora.getId());

    fab.setLayoutParams(lay);

    return fab;    
}
```

Estou tentando criar um botão `FloatingActionButton` no Android mas não consigo definir o tamanho do botão ou algo parecido com `app:fabSize="mini"`  pois não possui o método `setSize` e nem os `Enum` `FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programaticamente você pode usar o método `setSize` sim usando a *lib* `com.android.support:design:25.3.1`. A definição deve estar desta forma abaixo:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(this);
fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
```

Ou

```
fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_NORMAL);
```

Deves importar a *lib*:

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
```

No **Gradle**:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Veja mais [detalhes na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#setSize(int)).

Comment: Aqui não aparece essa opção. Tentei utilizar talvez pode ser versão

Comment: @VictorCésar conseguiu resolver o problema?!

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Estava na sdk 23 mudei para 25 e assim apareceu os metodos.